# Me muestra el siguiente error Notice: Undefined index: imagen

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo una problema me muestra el error Notice: Undefined index: imagen y no se porque sera :

```
   $sql="SELECT * FROM contribuyente WHERE id=$id";

    $ressql=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row ($ressql)){
            $id=$row[0];
            $nombre=$row[1];
            $rut=$row[2];
            $email=$row[3];
            $phone=$row[4];
            $direccion=$row[5];
            $poste=$row[6];
            $mensaje=$row[7];
            $comentario=$row[9];
            $estado=$row[8];
            $fecha=$row[10];
            $servicio=$row[11];
            $fecharec=$row[12];

        }

    ?>
    <section id="main" class="container 75%">
                <header>
                    <br><br><h2>Generar Reporte</h2>

                </header>   
<form action="update.php" method="POST" role="form">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                        <legend>Reporte</legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Folio</label>
                            <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $id ?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus required placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre ?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus required placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Fecha</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fecha" class="form-control" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $fecha ?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus required placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Rut</label>
                            <input type="email" name="rut" class="form-control" id="email"  value="<?php echo $rut ?>" readonly="readonly" required placeholder="Ingresa tu dirección de e-mail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Correo</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email"  value="<?php echo $email ?>" readonly="readonly" required placeholder="Ingresa tu dirección de e-mail">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usuario">Direccion</label>
                            <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" id="poste"  value="<?php echo $direccion ?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus required placeholder="usuario">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usuario">Poste</label>
                            <input type="text" name="poste" class="form-control" id="poste"  value="<?php echo $poste ?>" readonly="readonly" autofocus required placeholder="usuario">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Observacion</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mensaje" class="form-control" id="usuario"  value="<?php echo $mensaje ?>" readonly="readonly"  placeholder="usuario"></textarea>
                        </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Fecha recibido</label>
                            <input type="date" name="fecharec" step="1" min="2013-01-01" max="2030-12-31" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre">Estado</label>
                            <SELECT name="estado" size ="1" id="estado" style="width:300px " value="<?php echo $estado?>">
                                <option>-Seleccione Estado-</option>
                    <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                         <option value="Resuelto">Resuelto</option>"

                        </div></SELECT></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Servicio</label>

                    </head>
                      <form>
                        <?php 

                           $query_mostrar_tema = "SELECT * FROM materiales"; 
                           $mostrar_tema = mysqli_query($conexion,$query_mostrar_tema ) or die(mysqli_error()); 
                           $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostrar_tema); 
                           $totalRows_mostrar_tema = mysqli_num_rows($mostrar_tema); 
                            ?> 
                          <select id="tema" name="tema" onChange="actualizar()">> 
                            <option>-----Seleccione Servicio-----</option>
                          <?php do { ?> 
                          <option value="<?php echo $row_mostrar_tema['nombre']?>"><?php echo $row_mostrar_tema['nombre']?> 
                          </option> 
                          <?php 
                          } while ($row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mostrar_tema));
                          $rows = mysqli_num_rows($tema); 
                          if($rows > 0) { 
                            mysqli_data_seek($tema, 0); 
                          $row_mostrar_tema = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tema); 
                            } 
                           ?> 
                               </select>
                               <script language="javascript">

                                var datos = [];

                               function actualizar() {

                              var select = document.querySelector('#tema').value
                              var eltexto = document.querySelector('#eltexto');
                              datos.push(select);
                              eltexto.value =  datos.join("\n");;
                              }
                             </Script>
                             <br>
                          <textarea id="eltexto" name="servicio" value="<?php echo $servicio?>" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label> 
                           <input id="imagen" name="imagen" size="30" type="file" />
                            </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usuario">Observacion</label>
                            <textarea name="comentario"  rows="10"  class="form-control" id=""  value=""   placeholder="Ingrese observacion"></textarea> 
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar Reporte</button>
                        <a href="usuario.php" title='Editar datos' class='btn btn-danger'>Volver</a>
```

y este es mi  codigo que me actualiza los datos

```
  <?php

     extract($_POST);   //extraer todos los valores del metodo post del formulario de actualizar
$server = "localhost";
              $usuario = "root";
             $contraseña = "";
             $bd = "bdpagina";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");

$nombre_img = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['imagen']['type'];
$tamano = $_FILES['imagen']['size'];
if (($nombre_img == !NULL) && ($_FILES['imagen']['size'] <= 200000)) 
{
 //indicamos los formatos que permitimos subir a nuestro servidor
 if (($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/gif")
 || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
 || ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"] == "image/png"))
 {
  // Ruta donde se guardarán las imágenes que subamos
  $directorio = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images';
  // Muevo la imagen desde el directorio temporal a nuestra ruta indicada anteriormente
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$directorio.$nombre_img);
   } 
   else 
   {
   //si no cumple con el formato
   echo "No se puede subir una imagen con ese formato ";
 }
 } 
  else 
{
   //si existe la variable pero se pasa del tamaño permitido
   if($nombre_img == !NULL) echo "La imagen es demasiado grande "; 
}


   $sentencia = "UPDATE contribuyente SET estado = '$estado', comentario = '$comentario', servicio = '$servicio' , fecha_rec ='$fecharec' , imagen='$nombre_img' WHERE contribuyente. id = '$id'";
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
$resent=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
if ($resent==null) {
    echo "Error de procesamieno no se han actuaizado los datos";
    echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';
            echo "<script>location.href='usuario.php'</script>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

para que el se envie la imagen agrega esto al form: enctype="multipart/form-data

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```